# How to have two versions of the same application installed on the same PC?

Tags: c#

I have two versions of the same application. I want to install them to the same PC. When I install I get the error :

> Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.

Is there something I can do in the version settings?

Comment: Put them in different directories (like Microsoft Office does, for example). c:\Program Files\Company\Product\Version

Comment: But software version is stored in registry. Even if you do as Adriano said, still it will give this error.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal yes and no. I suppose he is using Windows Installer. Its behavior is defined in the installation project properties, how it works can be customized (if he wants to keep side-by-side installations) using ProductCode, Version and UpgradeCode properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need two version are installed in the same PC.

If you want, you can change the version(please find screenshot below e.g 2.7 => 2.8). There will be a popup windows that ask you to change ProductCode. If you say yes to the dialog. VS will change your product code for you. You can install newer version.

[image]

Comment: the second application crashes

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx) gives a good explaination of what the UpgradeCode, ProductCode and PackageCodes are used for. It looks like you will need to change the UpgradeCode.

From above Link

> the windows installer will use the UpgradeCode to decide if previous versions of this product are already present on the system.